# xgboost result is not stable

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

Here is my xgboost hyperparameters

```
xgb = XGBClassifier(
     bagging_fraction= 0.8,
     boosting= 'gbdt',
    colsample_bytree= 0.7,
    feature_fraction= 0.9,
    learning_rate= 0.05,
    max_bin= 32,
    max_depth= 10,
    min_child_weight= 11,
    missing= -999,
    n_estimators= 400,
    nthread= 4,
    num_leaves= 80,
    predictor= 'gpu_predictor',
    seed= 1337,
    silent= 1,
    subsample= 0.8,
    tree_method= 'gpu_hist',
    metric = 'logloss',
    verbose= True
)
```

my result is not very stable 
which parameter should I add to make it stable?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not stable"?